# My Hardhat test are inconsistent

Tags: hardhat, rpc, test

I'm stuck with an issue, where my tests runs yields different errors while the code doesn't change.

I'm using hardhat + chai, with an archive node service like Alchemy which allows me to fork the chain at a special block (`blockNumber: xxxx` in hardhat.config.js).

Currently, the main is that this inconsistent behavior breaks my CI pipeline, when it shouldn't, as the environment is sandboxed and the forking always happens at the same block.

Did anyone meet the same issue before?